# Import error in plotly while using FigureWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to use run the following commands in Jupyter notebook :

```
import ipywidgets
import plotly.graph_objs as go
print(ipywidgets.__version__)

f = go.FigureWidget()
f
```

I am getting the following error

```
ImportError: Please install ipywidgets>=7.0.0 to use the FigureWidget class
```

My ipywidgets version is 7.5.1. How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I first upgraded my `pip` by finding the location of `python.exe` and running `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` on my Terminal.

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '~\Documents\python_projects\lost_sales_validation\venv_lost_sales\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Once I had the most updated version of `pip` I ran `pip install ipywidgets --upgrade`.