# error in using FigureWidget() of the plotly.graph_objects

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.graph-objects

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving the below issue. i have tried to find a resolution to the error messages in existing questions (e.g., [Import error in plotly while using FigureWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577678/import-error-in-plotly-while-using-figurewidget)) but nothing has worked.

I have python code using plotly with following imports (on Mac OS):

```
# Import the modules
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from flask import Flask
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
```

and instantiation :

```
# Component 1
 
countfig = go.FigureWidget()
```

On running this I am getting an error message:

```
ImportError: Please install ipywidgets>=7.0.0 to use the FigureWidget class
```

To resolve this issue, I installed the ipywidgets package with the following pip command.

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

which returns the installation confirmation

> Successfully installed ipywidgets-8.0.6

Now when I run the python code again, the error message changes to :

```
raise NotImplementedError("Cannot ")
```

NotImplementedError: Cannot

This is where i have been for over a day.I have tried a few resolutions but these lead to the same outcome.

I would appreciate greatly if someone can help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Graph objects must first be imported, so please add the following. `import plotly.graph_objects as go`

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. I did not copy this earlier in original question but I have the following imports as well already : 
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go